# Windows Runtime: How to set image in a ellipse shape button?

Tags: c#, windows-runtime, winrt-xaml

```
<Button x:Name="btnProfilePicture" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Click="btnProfilePicture_Click">
    <Button.Template>
        <ControlTemplate>
            <Ellipse x:Name="ellipsePicture" Fill="Turquoise" Width="150" Height="150" Stroke="White" StrokeThickness="10">
            </Ellipse>
        </ControlTemplate>
    </Button.Template>
</Button >
```

I have a button in ellipse shape, with color fill by default.
I want to change the fill to an image in code-behind in runtime.

How can I do this?

More info: 
I tried to set the ellipse fill by using the "ellipsePicture" name but this name cannot be referenced in the code behind but I dont know the reason.

Comment: it's a windows runtime / metro app.

Comment: Do check out this aricle https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/hh868203.aspx

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try the following code..

```
<Button x:Name="BtnProfilePicture" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top" Margin="10">
            <Button.Template>
                <ControlTemplate>
                    <Grid Height="100">
                        <Ellipse x:Name="ellipsePicture" Fill="{TemplateBinding Background}"/>
                    </Grid>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Button.Template>
        </Button >
```

On your code behind add the following line..

```
BtnProfilePicture.BackgroundImage = 
           new ImageBrush { ImageSource = LoadBackgroundImage(yourfilename.jpg)};
```

Vote me if this works!

Comment: Thanks a lot. It works fine! The exact code is following:                 btnProfilePicture.Background= new ImageBrush
                    {
                        ImageSource = new BitmapImage(new Uri(fullpath))
                    };

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<Button x:Name="btnProfilePicture" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Click="btnProfilePicture_Click">
<Button.Template>
    <ControlTemplate>
        <Ellipse x:Name="ellipsePicture" Width="150" Height="150" Stroke="White" StrokeThickness="10">
            <Ellipse.Fill>
                <ImageBrush ImageSource="/DessCol;component/Images/Recommencer.ico"/>
            </Ellipse.Fill>
        </Ellipse>
    </ControlTemplate>
</Button.Template>
```

Comment: I want to do this in code behind by runtime instead of hard-code it in xaml.

Answer (score 0):

Try it. After this modify you can set image to content. This changes you can made at XAML and runtime.

```
      <Button Content="C:\Round.JPG">
            <Button.Template>
                <ControlTemplate>
                    <Ellipse x:Name="ellipsePicture" Width="150" Height="150" Stroke="White" StrokeThickness="10">
                        <Ellipse.Fill>
                            <ImageBrush ImageSource="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type Button}},
                                                          Path=Content}"/>
                        </Ellipse.Fill>
                    </Ellipse>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Button.Template>
        </Button>
```

Comment: thanks for your comment, but I want to do it in code behind in runtime.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Background property of the button to set image on the background.You can use it from code behind also like:

```
public BitmapImage LoadBackgroundImage(string fileName)
{
            var image = new BitmapImage();
            try
            {
                image.BeginInit();
                if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(fileName) && File.Exists(fileName))
                {
                    var bytes = File.ReadAllBytes(fileName);
                    image.StreamSource = new MemoryStream(bytes);
                }
                else
                {
                    var bytes = File.ReadAllBytes(Path.GetFullPath(Properties.Resources.DefaultBackgroundImage));
                    image.StreamSource = new MemoryStream(bytes);
                }
                image.CacheOption = BitmapCacheOption.OnLoad;
                image.EndInit();
                image.Freeze();
            }
            catch (FileNotFoundException ex)
            {
                  throw ex;
            }

            return image;
        }
```

in your button click event add the following line

btnProfilePicture.Background=LoadBackgroundImage(yourfilename.jpg);
//you can use *.jpg,*.jpeg,*.png

Comment: but this just load the image into the button, but not in the ellipse shape.

Comment: Use the above code to fill the image in Ellipse like "ellipsePicture.Fill=LoadBackgroundImage(yourfilename.jpg);"

Comment: I tried this but the "ellipsePicture" seems cannot be referenced in the code behind. I don't know whether it is because it is in a control template, or nested in button control or whatever.