# How to assign ImageBrush to Fill property of Ellipse in Windows 10 UWP c#?

Tags: c#, windows-10-universal

I want to assign ImageBrush to Fill property of Ellipse using c#. My XAML and C# code as following

XAML Code

```
<Ellipse Grid.Column="0"
         Margin="7"
         x:Name="userEllipse"
         Stretch="Uniform"/>
```

C# Code

```
ImageBrush imageBrush=new ImageBrush();
imageBrush.ImageSource=new BitmapImage(new Uri(url,UriKind.RelativeorAbsolute));
userEllipse.Fill=imageBrush;
```

This code is not working nor it's giving me any error. Can someone suggest what I am doing wrong? I can't assign URL​ in XAML as it is coming from the server.

Answer (score 0):

Got the alternative to achieve my requirement on the following URL

[Image in Ellipse shape](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31113614/windows-runtime-how-to-set-image-in-a-ellipse-shape-button)

Hope it helps someone.